# Custom struct and custom functions (adding 7 days to user input date)

Tags: c, function, struct

New date always returns as 1/19/3, format needs to be mm/dd/yyyy. Also needs to be the correct date. I cannot find where in which par of the new date calculation the problems is occurring.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    };

struct date addSeven(struct date addSev) {
    addSev.day += 7;
 // Months with 31 days
    if ((addSev.month == 1 || // January
        addSev.month == 3 || // March
        addSev.month == 5 || // May
        addSev.month == 7 || // July
        addSev.month == 8 || // August
        addSev.month == 10 || // October
        addSev.month == 12) // December
        && addSev.day > 31) {
            addSev.day -= 31; // Equivalent to addSev.day = addSev.day - 31;
            addSev.month += 1;
            }
    // Months with 30 days
        else if ((addSev.month == 4 || // April
        addSev.month == 6 || // June
        addSev.month == 9 || // September
        addSev.month == 11) // November
        && addSev.day > 30) {
            addSev.day -= 30;
            addSev.month += 1;
            }
    // February
        else {
            if (addSev.year % 4 == 0 && addSev.day > 29) { // Leap year
                addSev.day -= 29;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }  
            else if (addSev.day > 28) {
                addSev.day -= 28;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
            }
    if ((addSev.day == 25)
            && addSev.day > 31) {
            addSev.day -= 31; // Equivalent to addSev.day = addSev.day - 31;
            addSev.month += 1;
            }
        else if ((addSev.day == 24)
                && addSev.day > 30) {
                    addSev.day -= 30;
                    addSev.month += 1;
                    }
        else {
            if (addSev.year % 4 == 0 && addSev.day > 29) { // Leap year
                addSev.day -= 29;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
            else if (addSev.day > 28) {
                addSev.day -= 28;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
         if (addSev.month > 12) {
            addSev.month = 1; addSev.year += 1;
            }
        return addSev;
        }
    }


int main () {
    struct date origDate, newDate;
    newDate = addSeven (origDate);
    printf("Enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format:");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&origDate.month,&origDate.day,&origDate.year);

    printf("\n%d/%d/%d\n", origDate);
    printf("\n%d/%d/%d\n", newDate);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should change the title. Programming is all about custom structs and custom functions.

Comment: `&month,&day,&year`...wait they are not _normal_ variables, they are member variable of _some_ structure variable.

Comment: `printf("%d/%d/%d", origDate);` has two missing arguments.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm.

Comment: *mm/dd/yyyy format* - [:-(](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to return the date 7 days afterwards from the inputted one. In sequence, what you need to do is

1. Add the `day` from the struct by 7
2. Check whether the `day`'s value goes over the `month`'s day amount. If it is, decrement the `day` by how many days the corresponding `month` has. Then increment the `month` by 1
3. Check whether the `month` goes over 12 (There's only 12 months in a year). Suppose it is, get the `month`'s value to 1, then increment the `year` by 1

These steps cover what your function need to do.

Since the date will be stored in `struct date`, the process will also use `struct date`. That said, this line is unnecessary in a way.

```
int origDate, newDate;
```

You are going to use `struct date`, so `int` is incompatible for what you're going to do. There are ways to fix this but for now I suggest to change the `int` to `struct date`. Then you can erase this line of code.

```
struct date datecalc;
```

The idea is two variable with datatype `struct date` is needed: one for input, and one for post-processing. Don't be surprised if someone else suggests only one variable. Like I said, there are many ways to do this. For now, let's stick with the method I'm going to tell you.

Now, you need to receive user's input. `struct`'s member can be accessed using period. Using our variable before, let's say if you're going to fill in value `1999` into `origDate`'s `year`, this is what you would do

```
origDate.year = 1999;
```

See that I accessed `year` from `origDate` by giving a period between them. The same way goes to the other member of `struct date`. This line is problematic.

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&month,&day,&year);
```

The compiler would flip a table on you because in your program, variable `month`, `day` and `year` can't be found. Of course, they're in `struct date`. But these variables need an instance sheltering them to be usable (think it this way: before using a `TV`, you need `electricity`. Once you have `electricity`, you have all the `TV`'s functionality). To resolve this, you need a variable with datatype `struct date`. After then, the `month`, `day`, and `year` is exist via `struct date` variable.

To fix the code, access each member via the variable (e.g. `origDate`) so the line would look like this.

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &origDate.month, &origDate.day, &origDate.year);
```

So far we have covered the input. Now let's deal with the processing part. Recall the steps I have stated before. These steps shows that `day`, `month`, and `year` is needed and they can be found in `struct date`. So in the `addSeven` function, the parameter you need must have `struct date` datatype.

```
int addSeven(struct date addSev)
```

The outcome of the processing part is the date with 7 days ahead of the input. Since we expect the output to be a date, let's change the return datatype `int` to `struct date`.

```
struct date addSeven(struct date addSev)
```

Bingo. Your function prototype.

Let's setup the function.

1. Add the `day` from the struct by 7

   ```
   addSev.day += 7; // Equivalent to addSev.day = addSev.day + 7;
   ```
2. Check whether the `day`'s value goes over the `month`'s day amount

   ```
   // Months with 31 days
   if ((addSev.month == 1 || // January
        addSev.month == 3 || // March
        addSev.month == 5 || // May
        addSev.month == 7 || // July
        addSev.month == 8 || // August
        addSev.month == 10 || // October
        addSev.month == 12) // December
        && addSev.day > 31)
   {
       addSev.day -= 31; // Equivalent to addSev.day = addSev.day - 31;
       addSev.month += 1;
   }
   // Months with 30 days
   else if ((addSev.month == 4 || // April
             addSev.month == 6 || // June
             addSev.month == 9 || // September
             addSev.month == 11) // November
             && addSev.day > 30)
   {
       addSev.day -= 30;
       addSev.month += 1;
   }
   // February
   else
   {
       if (addSev.year % 4 == 0 && addSev.day > 29) // Leap year
       {
           addSev.day -= 29;
           addSev.month += 1;
       }
       else if (addSev.day > 28)
       {
           addSev.day -= 28;
           addSev.month += 1;
       }
   }
   ```

   Yes this is lengthy. I suggest to make another function to do the 'day overflow check'.
3. Check whether the `month` goes over 12

   if (addSev.month > 12)
   {
       addSev.month = 1;
       addSev.year += 1;
   }

After all this steps, return `addSev`.

To use this function, just assign `origDate` as parameter, and store the return value into `newDate`.

```
newDate = addSeven (origDate);
```

Finally, to print the value has the same idea with receiving user input. Only without ampersand (`&`) but I'm sure you already know that.

Comment: Quite an exemplary description. I don't work with structs much, but you've made it much clearer.

Comment: First off, thank you for your help mghazian, that is incredibly helpful. I have it working for the most part, however when I put in  new date of 5/27/1985 it prints:


    '5/27/1985

    1/19/3` 


I have been trying to trouble shoot it but I do not know what I am missing.

Comment: @PhilipHudson I don't know why the first `printf` line works, but by your explanation, your second `printf` line is problematic. `%d` needs to be assigned _something_, and many of the `%d` hasn't been so. Since your format is mm/dd/yyyy, you would want to assign the first `%d` with the `date`'s `month`. The second with `date`'s `day`, and the third with `date`'s `year`. Take a look again when the program receive user input. That's how it should be done too when printing since the value you need is a member of a struct (i.e. `newDate.day` etc.)

Comment: In your edited code, there's `printf("\n%d/%d/%d\n", newDate);`. Each of `%d` technically didn't get any value to be assigned with. What you would do is assign each %d with each member of `newDate` i.e. `newDate.month, newDate.day, newDate.year`

Comment: I made the change however it now always returns `2686868/4201214/4201120`

Comment: @PhilipHudson `newDate = addSeven (origDate);` is why it returns gibberish number. You assigned `newDate` when `origDate` contains nothing. You should assign `newDate` after user inputs `origDate`. To clarify, after `scanf` assign `newDate` with `addSeven`

Comment: That did it, You have been amazingly helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This program is successful for date calculation: MM/DD/YYYY.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*#include <stdbool.h> this header is to add a bool type and the true and false values as macro definitions.*/
#include <stdbool.h>
/*The time.h header defines four variable types, two macro and various functions for manipulating date and time.*/
#include <time.h>

    /*two variable with datatype struct date is needed for this program, one for the output, and one for post processing.*/
    struct date{
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    };
    bool leapYear(int year){
        if (year % 400 == 0|| (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100!=0))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    int days_in_month(struct date d){
        int max_days;

        if (d.month == 2){
                if (leapYear(d.year) == true)
                    max_days = 29;
                else
                    max_days = 28;

        }
        else if (d.month == 4 || d.month == 6 || d.month == 9 || d.month == 11)
            max_days = 30;
        else
            max_days = 31;
        return max_days;

    }
    struct date add_days(struct date d, int days){
        d.day += days;
        int max_days = days_in_month(d);

        if (d.day > max_days){
            d.day = d.day - max_days;
            d.month++;

        }
        if (d.month >12){
                d.month = d.month - 12;
                d.year++;

        }
        return d;

    }
    int main (void){
        int days = 7;
        bool valid = false;
        struct date d;
        struct date new_date;

        while (!valid){
               printf("Enter a date in the format of MM/DD/YYYY.\n");
               scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d.month, &d.day, &d.year);

               if (d.year >= 0 && d.year <= 9999 && d.day <= days_in_month(d) && d.day > 0 && d.month <= 12 && d.month >=1){
                   valid = true;

               }
               else {
                    printf("\nInvalid date. Enter date in format MM/DD/YYYY\n");


               }

        }
        printf("\nDate entered: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", d.month, d.day, d.year);
        new_date = add_days (d, days);
        printf(" 7 days later: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", new_date.month, new_date.day,new_date.year);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).